# How to get class from list by value therein?

Tags: java

I have class that stores groups' permissions for single element. In it, I've also class for single group's permissions set. The solution is simple, [looks that](http://screencloud.net/v/pXAI).

But I have no idea how can I get single permissions set using value in it (in `group_id`). How can I do that?

```
public class PermissionsData {
    private List<PermissionsDataSingle> permissionsData;

    PermissionsData(List<PermissionsDataSingle> permissionsData) {
        this.permissionsData = permissionsData;
    }

    public PermissionsDataSingle getPermissionsByGroupID(int group_id) {
        // ToDo
    }

    public class PermissionsDataSingle {
        public int group_id;
        public boolean canView;
        public boolean canRead;
        public boolean canReply;
        public boolean canStart;
        public boolean canUpload;
        public boolean canDownload;
        PermissionsDataSingle(int group_id, boolean canView, boolean canRead, boolean canReply, boolean canStart, boolean canUpload, boolean canDownload) {
            this.group_id = group_id;
            this.canView = canView;
            this.canRead = canRead;
            this.canReply = canReply;
            this.canStart = canStart;
            this.canUpload = canUpload;
            this.canDownload = canDownload;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a `List<PermissionsDataSingle>`.  Use a `Map<Integer,PermissionsDataSingle>` instead, where the key is the `group_id`.  Make it a `HashMap` if the order is unimportant, or a `LinkedHashMap` if order is important.  If multiple `PermissionsDataSingle` objects can share the same `group_id` value, then get your hands on Guava and use a `HashMultimap`.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is always very short, you can simply iterate through it and check the group_id for each entry. Otherwise it's better to use a map.

```
for (PermissionsDataSingle pds : permissionsData) {
    if (pds.group_id == group_id) {
        return pds;
    }
}
// Not found
```